# List is not rerendered in react hooks with button onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a simple ul list that starts empty, when I click on the add item button it adds the element to the dom (I can see it by inspecting) but it just don't really renders the li item on the screen...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Index from './Index.css'

const Animatedlist = (props) => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const listItems = items.map((item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>)

    const addItem = () => {
        console.log('asdasd6')

         setItems([
            ...items,
            {
                id: items.length,
                value: 'New Item'+items.length
            }
        ])

        return items

    }

        return ( 
            <>
                <ul>
                    {/* {items.map(item => { return <li key={item.id}> {item.value} </li> })} */}
                    {listItems}
                </ul>

                <button onClick={addItem}>{props.buttonText}</button>



                <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}></button>
            </>
        )

}

export default Animatedlist
```

Comment: The code looks all right. Please add a runnable code snippet that reproduces the problem to the question.

Comment: Agreed. The code is fine. It must be something outside of this module

Comment: @JonathanRys, why? Because it doesn't have React 16.8? You can add any version of React using the HTML section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks and works OK:

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React;

const Animatedlist = (props) => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const listItems = items.map((item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>)

    const addItem = () => {
        console.log('asdasd6')

         setItems([
            ...items,
            {
                id: items.length,
                value: 'New Item'+items.length
            }
        ])

        return items

    }

        // I've used React.Fragment because the SO compiler doesn't support <>
        return ( 
            <Fragment>
                <ul>
                    {/* {items.map(item => { return <li key={item.id}> {item.value} </li> })} */}
                    {listItems}
                </ul>

                <button onClick={addItem}>{props.buttonText}</button>



                <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}></button>
            </Fragment>
        )

}

ReactDOM.render(<Animatedlist buttonText="Add item" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.8.6/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If you see in the browser DOM inspector that the elements are added to the DOM and they are not visible, the only possible reason is CSS. Make sure that the `<li>`s are not hidden using `display: none;`, `visibility: hidden;`, `opacity: 0;`, `left: -9999px;`, etc.